# How to recover gmail address

Tags: gmail, google-account, data-recovery

So, Awhile back I got a new phone and my number changed.  I went to My Google Account page but It would not let me sign in to change my number.  Been 5 months now..but It is still logged onto an older phone (LG Pheonix).  I did account recovery, Google emailed me back they could not confirm it was me. What now?

Comment: This question doesn't have anything to with Android. It is just a basic Google.com account support question. If you can't find an answer in their official support, the next place to ask would be the webapps site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This also happened to me. What I did was, I told them my basic information stored in that google account, including on how it was used (for games, payments etc.)

Comment: I did the same, but they said they had to review my information.  Kept getting emails back to another gmail address saying based on my info they could not determine if it was my account.  Did you actually get your account recovered? @ervin maitim

Comment: Yes I recovered my email account. I also included my old passwords for that email to convince them. My security questions as well. @bsplaylist

Comment: I might add, I'm still logged onto my old phone with the email I cannot sign into anywhere else..it still works through wi-fi connection.  I know my password, but the want my old phone number as I had 2 step verification on.

Comment: That was also my problem, because I lost my phone number used in the 2-step verification. So I googled, on bypassing it. And it says, recovering the account. May I also add that I tried 3 times before I recovered my email. Try and try, and tell google most of the things you've done using that email, and also; as you can still access it in your old phone, include some emails sent or received via that email in the recovery.